# start new shell from perl script and execute the rest of code on the child shell

Tags: perl

I want to start a new shell from perl (which I'm doing by `exec` statement). When child shell starts, i want to print some message on the new shell and want to run another perl script on the child shell.

I'm doing this:

```
exec $ENV{SHELL};
```

Please help.

Comment: show how do you used the "exec statement". e.g. show what you tried. ;) (you could edit your question)

Comment: There's not gonna be a *child shell* with `exec` (children are only created by *fork()*). Your perl script is **replaced** by whatever program you exec. The proper term would be **the exec'ed shell**. Could you please rephrase your question so we might understand it better?

Comment: Please check the output of ps command before and after executing the perl script having simple exec $ENV{SHELL}. It will actually create a child shell

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do.

- exec() will return without output/status and doesn't fork

  - http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec.html
- system() will fork from the Perl process and return a status (exitcode)

  - http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html

What I think you're after is back ticks ``

Check out http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%60STRING%60 which has some good examples on how to capture the output of an external command.  Note that backticks do fork.

I like to use Perls quote like operator `qx` in lieu of backticks.

http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators

**Example:**

```
my $ls = qx/ls/;
my $ret_ls = $? >> 8;

print "Output: $ls\nExit Code: $ret_ls";
```

**Example other script:**

```
my $other_script_output = qx{/path/to/other_script.pl};
my $ret_other_script = $? >> 8;

print "Output: $other_script_output\nExit Code: $ret_other_script";
```

If you're looking for interacting with that process programmatically then you're going to be diving into open2 / open3.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '|-', $ENV{SHELL};
print $fh <<'EOF';
echo "$0: From shell goes hell"
EOF
```

Note `'` around `'EOF'` which disables Perl interpolation of shell script but `$0` is interpolated by shell. You would have to escape `\$0` otherwise to obtain the shell executable. See [perlop Here-document](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#%3c%3cEOF) for more details.

You can use existing file handle for this purpose as well

```
use strict;
use warnings;

close STDIN;
open STDIN, '<&', \*DATA;
exec $ENV{SHELL};
__DATA__
echo "$0: From shell goes hell"
```

Note `open my $fh, '|-', $ENV{SHELL};` is just syntactic sugar for `open my $fh, '|-' or exec $ENV{SHELL};` where `open my $fh, '|-'` is syntactic sugar for some `pipe`, `close`, `dup`, `fork` juggling.

But this code will not work

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $script = <<'EOF';
echo "$0: From shell goes hell"
EOF

close STDIN;
open STDIN, '<', \$script; # this is not real file handler!
exec $ENV{SHELL};
```